# VB.Net SQL Databases- How to Save Changes to Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

My database program is fully functional and when I add new entries to the database they appear on my DataGridView correctly. However after I close the program these changes are not saved. How do I save the changes back to the database? Here's my code:

```
    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.MainDatabaseConnectionString)
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES('Something','Test');"
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn)
    Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    'Open Connection
    conn.Open()
    'Execute Query
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    'Close Connection
    conn.Close()

    'Update DataGridView
    Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UsersDataSet.Users)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, you need more the a reader :)

There are many ways to go.  This link gives a reasonable example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

The key thing:

> To start, the GridView's SqlDataSource  must contain an UpdateCommand
>   with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert something into the DB you can do this

```
Dim mySQLCommand As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
mySQLCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES('Something','Test');"
mySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

you might also want to parameterize your variables to prevent sql injections

```
mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@variable_name", SqlDBType.NvarChar).value = variable
```

and using `@variable_name` in the insert

```
mySQLCommand.CommandText = INSERT INTO Users VALUES(@variable_name, @variable_name2)
```